# Web font with Unicode Support ⸵▬ ℩ɟ

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, web-fonts

I'm digitizing an ancient math book for the web. Thus I'm looking for a monospace or serif font that supports unicode characters.

Everson Mono was perfect but it is not allowed to be embedded in websites.

Here are in particular the characters that are often problematic:

> ⸵▬℩ɟ

- U+2E35
- U+25AC
- U+2129
- U+025F

Bold and italic versions would be appreciated.

Comment: https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/roboto-mono

Comment: The first character is not recognised

Comment: That's weird. It seems to work for me. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/7XbX11V)

Comment: I guess it's simply because your browser uses one of the fonts you installed to render the character that doesn't belong to Roboto.

Comment: Nowadays, "a font that supports unicode characters" is practically a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(language)). The vast, vast majority of web fonts and web pages *are* in Unicode. But it would help us help you if you specified the Unicode codepoints of your problematic characters.

Comment: Done, thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

"Unicode character support" is a very broad term. *ALL* characters are part of the unicode specification. However, [Noto fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) have as a goal to cover the whole of unicode, and they've come a long way. They're libre and open source, so you can freely embed them in webpages. There is a serif and a mono version, though the latter does not have as wide language suppoort as the sans/serif versions.
Some versions are hosted in google fonts.

Comment: That’s the reason why I specified some characters I need the font to support and Noto doesn’t